# pecl memcached on windows

Tags: php, windows-xp, memcached, pecl

I'm using Windows XP SP3 and I need to install libmemcached (**NOT MEMCACHE**), the php class, through PECL. However, every time I try to it tells me that it can't find memcached.dsp.

Is there a way to install libmemcached on windows through PECL?

Comment: Did you eventually find php_memcached.dll ? I'm looking for it as well.

Comment: nope, never found it. the developer that was also on the project I needed it for ended up disabling memcached for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading php_memcache.dll from Pierre's server : http://downloads.php.net/pierre/ (You'll find it inside php_memcache-*something*.zip)

That way, you won't have to compile it yourself -- which is not generally that easy on windows...

There are also several other extensions already compiled, there -- As I understand, it's some kind of "replacement" for [pecl4win.php.net](http://pecl4win.php.net/) *(at least for a couple of extensions ; not all of them, though)* until extensions are put on [windows.php.net](http://windows.php.net/)

Comment: well here's the thing, I need php_memcached, not php_memcache. The Memcache class works fine, but Memcached itself doesn't really.